# How to create a grid based map?

Tags: c#, mud

I'm trying to make a map like this in C#:

```
   0     1    
0 [ ]---[ ]   
   |     |    
   |     |    
1 [ ]---[ ]
```

Simple grid with rooms at `(0,0)`, `(1,0)`, `(0,1)` and `(1,1)`

I have tried doing this and have an example here https://dotnetfiddle.net/3qzBhy

But my output is:
    `[ ]|||| [ ]`

I don't get why and not sure if calling `.ToString()` on a StringBuilder makes it lose its formatting such as new lines.

I also had trouble finding a way to store coordinates

```
Public SortedList<int, int> Rooms ()
    {
        var roomList = new SortedList<int, int>(); 

        roomList.Add(0,0);
        roomList.Add(1,0);
        //roomList.Add(0,1);
        //roomList.Add(1,1);

        return roomList;
    }
```

`roomList.Add(0,1)` and `roomList.Add(1,1)` are duplicates because the keys `0` and `1` are already used. How can I store a list of coordinates?

Comment: From your code, I don't get what you are saying about `StringBuilder`.  Please elaborate. Is there a reason you cannot use a two-dimensional array, or a list which holds instances of `Point`?

Comment: Your vertical and horizontal connectors are swapped, and since you don't have rooms at Y=1, there are no vertical connectors.

Comment: Quick fix for the duplicate Keys issue: Instead of a `SortedList<int,int>` use a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` (Key = X = Item1, Value = Y = Item2).

Comment: Also: Output where? You won't have a lot of fun with text formatting, if you are not using a Console font.

Comment: Other issues: Slashes are escaped with another slash, not with single-quotes. If you are trying to build the map room by room, you can't just *append* multiple lines at once .

Comment: @jens Don't worry about that. The output is to a webpage within <pre> tags the Dotnet fiddle outputs to a console so will work there too. @ Manfred Thanks for that just reading up on Tuples now

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer _ you can't just append multiple lines at once_ I am unsure on the approach to build this grid. Appending lines was my 1st thought, if that's not possible I guess I need to rethink my whole approach

Comment: Instead of SortedList<int, int> or List<Tuple<int, int>> I'd suggest, just for now to use List<Point>  (System.Drawing.Point), it gives you predefined X and Y fields

Comment: @LiamKenneth Have you considered using a "half-step" Grid instead? Basically a Grid that alternates between Rooms and connectors - [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q20sL.png)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer "half-step" grid looks exactly like what I am trying to do.

Comment: @LiamKenneth [Ugly, non-optimzed, proof-of-concept here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/p7zhzq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of spreading my opinions via comments I'll just dump em all here as an answer:

> I also had trouble finding a way to store coordinates

`SortedLists`, `Dictionaries`, etc. won't work. It would be best to just use a regular `List` filled with `Tuples`, `Points` or a class of your own until you find a better solution.

Since those rooms maybe won't stay empty you could write your own classes, e.g.:

```
class Tile
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public virtual void Draw(StringBuilder map)
    {
        map.Append("   ");
    }
}

class Room : Tile
{ 
    public int EnemyType { get; set; }
    public int Reward { get; set; }

    public override void Draw(StringBuilder map)
    {
        map.Append("[ ]");
    }
}

// etc.
```

> I don't get why and not sure if calling .ToString() on a StringBuilder makes it lose its formatting such as new lines.

It doesn't. You didn't have any newlines in your example because all rooms are at `Y = 0`

The current attempt won't work if you draw multiple lines at once and string them together. Instead you could use something like a "half-step" grid.

[image]

You can find a small (ugly, non-optimzed, makeshift) example [here as a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/p7zhzq).

Comment: Thanks, this works very well and gives me a good understanding on how to  achieve what I want. You are correct about the custom class I will need one for the things you mentioned as well as denoting when to use a diagonal line to connect rooms I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problems with text-formatting and the console, and also the options Manfred already mentioned, here is an example which uses an array instead of a list. A room is a `true`-value at any given index, "no room" is represented by `false`.

Your `Rooms()`method looks like this then:

```
public bool[,] Rooms ()
{
    var roomList = new bool[,]{{true,false},{true,true}};
    return roomList;
}
```

Which makes you need to change `IsRoom(int, int)`to look like this:

```
public bool IsRoom(int x, int y)
{
    var rooms = Rooms();

    if(x<rooms.GetLength(0) && y<rooms.GetLength(1))
    {
        return (rooms[x,y]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also there was a line-break missing, which lead to having a vertcal connector on the same line as the next room. I changed it to be

```
        if (IsRoom(x, y + 1))
        {
            buildMap.Append("\r\n".PadLeft(4) + DrawVerticalConnector().PadRight(4));
            buildMap.Append("\r\n".PadLeft(4) + DrawVerticalConnector().PadRight(4)+ "\r\n".PadLeft(4));
        }
```